# Lightweight Like

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-like

I'm using fb:like/share/send etc within a variety of different apps/sites sometimes where the buttons are called to render several times, for example on a store with multiple items.

Problem is the like buttons are horribly bloaty. I'm using xfbml vers but there seems to be constant redirection going on in the background. With the buttons commented out, page renders snappy and nice, uncomment the like buttons and *everything* grinds to a veritable halt.

I've seem some blackhat solutions for obscuring the buttons etc. but all i'm really after is simply a lighter-weight like solution. Does anyone know of any way you can call 'like' from the api so that it might be attached to an event and cut-out fb's horrible solution?

Answer (score 1):

I use the deprecated Share method, which adds one line of HTML and small image to my pages. This is important to me. My blog is used by many older people with slow machines, slow Internet connections and obsolete browsers. So I keep my pages small and simple.

I tried switching to the Like button, but it pages took 5 or even 10 times as long to load.

So no answer, I'm afraid - aside from sticking with Share. But supporting your call for a lighter weight Like button. A small image, half a dozen lines of HTML and the option of no additional server call would be great.